# BETWEEN query on two indexed columns exponentially takes longer on minimal changes to LIMIT

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, optimization, query-performance

This is a minimal example of my problem, but I reproduced the problem with this structure. I have the following table:

```
| column name    | type        |
|----------------+-------------|
| id             | PRIMARY KEY |
| id_start       | INT         |
| id_end         | INT         |
|----------------+-------------|
```

This table contains roughly one billion (1,000,000,000) rows. The `_start` and `_end` columns are indexed. This is InnoDB using Btree indices.

Some background information: This is sensor data with start and end timestamps. The timestamps itself are kept in another table, which is referenced from this one. Thus I only work with the `id` columns here.

Following query returns around 15,000 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 310000 BETWEEN id_start AND id_end;
```

The problem is that query takes very long to return anything (MySQL Workbench duration 1 sec / fetch 220 sec).

If I append `LIMIT 14000` to the query it returns almost immediately. The closer I go with the `LIMIT` parameter to the expected 15000 resulting rows, the longer the query takes.

What could be the cause, that fetching 14,000 rows vs. 15,000 rows takes exponentially longer?

Some more bits of information which I am unsure of if they are of any relevance to this question:

- The DB Server is well configured (InnoDB buffers etc.).
- The DB Server has way more CPU power and memory than required. The whole dataset fits into memory.
- All columns in that table are not nullable.

As requested here is additional information regarding the table structure and the query.

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_start` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_end` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_end` (`id_end`),
  KEY `idx_start` (`id_start`),
  KEY `idx_start_end` (`id_start`,`id_end`),
  KEY `idx_end_start` (`id_end`,`id_start`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

And here the EXPLAIN statement for the query:

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+----------+---------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  |                  possible_keys                  |      key      | key_len | ref  |   rows   | filtered |     Extra     |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table | NULL       | range | "idx_start,idx_end,idx_start_end,idx_end_start" | idx_end_start |       9 | NULL | 20509120 |    50.00 | "Using where" |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+------+----------+----------+---------------+
```

Here is the result of a low `LIMIT` `EXPLAIN`:

```
'{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "27795648.61"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "table",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "idx_start",
        "idx_end",
        "idx_start_end",
        "idx_end_start"
      ],
      "key": "idx_end_start",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "id_end"
      ],
      "key_length": "9",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 19854034,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 9927018,
      "filtered": "50.00",
      "index_condition": "(310300 between `table`.`id_start` and `table`.`id_end`)",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "25810244.97",
        "eval_cost": "1985403.64",
        "prefix_cost": "27795648.61",
        "data_read_per_join": "4G"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "id",
        "id_start",
        "id_end"
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

and here is the result of a high `LIMIT` `EXPLAIN`:

```
'{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "27203639.01"
    },
    "table": {
      "table_name": "table",
      "access_type": "range",
      "possible_keys": [
        "idx_start",
        "idx_end",
        "idx_start_end",
        "idx_end_start"
      ],
      "key": "idx_end_start",
      "used_key_parts": [
        "id_end"
      ],
      "key_length": "9",
      "rows_examined_per_scan": 19431170,
      "rows_produced_per_join": 9715586,
      "filtered": "50.00",
      "index_condition": "(310300 between `table`.`id_start` and `table`.`id_end`)",
      "cost_info": {
        "read_cost": "25260521.78",
        "eval_cost": "1943117.23",
        "prefix_cost": "27203639.01",
        "data_read_per_join": "4G"
      },
      "used_columns": [
        "id",
        "id_start",
        "id_end"
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Please post the result of `EXPLAIN <your_query>;` and instead of explaining your table and still leaving questions open, you could simply post the result of `show create table <your_table>\G`. Another useful information could be `show indexes from <your_table>;`

Comment: Better yet, please provide `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` for a fast limit and a slow limit.

Comment: Alas, no clues in the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two questions:

- What's with `LIMIT` affecting performance?
- (The *real* question.)  How to speed up this kind of query on this kind of table.

This is a classic "tough task" in MySQL -- finding elements between a 'start' and 'end' value.

I address it with some extra complication in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges .  However, it requires that the ranges be non-overlapping.  (It is unclear whether your ranges will overlap.)

You say that `id_start` is really a pointer to another table where the actual timestamp is held?  And yet you use `WHERE 310000 BETWEEN id_start AND id_end`.  This implies that `id_start` and `id_end` are chronologically ordered, though not actually representations of "time"?  And ditto for `310000`?  Perhaps this is to use 4-byte INTs instead of larger `TIMESTAMP(6)` or something?

With `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`, we might be able to figure out why changing the `LIMIT` value affects performance.

How evenly are the times distributed?  Here's a *guess* at the difference you are seeing:  With a low value for `LIMIT`, the Optimizer's statistics suggest that a certain query plan will find the 14K quickly, but with the larger value, it will deduce that it may need to search far to find 15K rows.  The Optimizer has no concept of "time ranges".  Hence it can only use `INDEX(start)` or `INDEX(end)`; it does not know that `start<end` and other things that *you* know and could use to optimize the query.

Do you need `id` for anything else?  Are there other columns in the table?  *Both of these are important questions, since the following optimization may fail, depending on your answers.*

For this 3-column table, I would *consider* one of the following alternatives:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    start_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    end_id   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(start_id, end_id),  -- assumed unique
    INDEX      (end_id, start_id)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
-- assumes start-end pairs are unique
-- with a billion rows; fewer indexes is beneficial

CREATE TABLE x (
    start_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    end_id   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    id       INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(start_id, end_id, id),  -- id assures uniqueness
    INDEX      (end_id, start_id),
    INDEX(id) -- sufficient to keep AUTO_INCREMENT happy
ENGINE=InnoDB;
-- does not assume start-end pairs are unique
-- allows for FK to `id`
```

Notes:

- By having the PK start with `start_id` may help with performance.
- The performance of start..end queries is not solved.
- I have not assessed the benefit of these schemas if there are more columns.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. My table contains time series from around 15000 sensors. For one single sensor the timestamps do not overlap, which is why in the end I expect to see as many results as I have sensors sending data at the time. The timestamps are very evenly distributed, but there can be (very few) broken sensors, which haven't been sending data for a longer time.

EDIT: I will add EXPLAIN results to my question for fast and slow limits.

Comment: @Martin - Let me get a fuller picture...  How often does each sensor report?  Once a minute?  Once an hour?  Many of the sensors report at the "same" time; that is, how big is the "burst"?  Then there are some stragglers reporting in before the next burst?  Reporting in involves a new connection?  Is reporting in a MySQL operation?  HTTP?  REST?  Other type of call to a client that then talks to MySQL?

Comment: I get readings every few minutes. Some sensors change values up to 20 times a day, others only 2 or 3 times. It happens all the time that I get new values from multiple sensors at the same time. There is almost no regularity in the amount of data I receive sadly. 

Right now I collect the data from various sources via Python and do Batch INSERTS into the MySQL DB from my script. I'd like to build a web page that shows all sensor values at a certain point in time, which is why I want to know all sensor values which were reported at this time.

Comment: @Martin - OK.  Now, please explain the rationale for having `start` and `end` times for the query.  If we can avoid having `end` (by using `LIMIT` or `start + 10 minutes` or ...), we can eliminate the performance issue this question is centered around.

Comment: I thought it was cleaner than without. You are right, I should think about whether I really need the end timestamp. How would I go about querying all sensor values at a specific timestamp? GROUP BY sensor ID with a LIMIT in a sub-query and then JOIN that back to get the actual values?

Comment: @Martin - We need to agree on the meaning of "at a specific timestamp".  If we look at all the sensors during one hour, we will miss some; is that OK?  If, instead, we pick a 2-hour window, there are likely to be some duplicates; meanwhile the twice-a-day sensors are likely to be missing.  If you desire "_all_ sensor readings at about 8 o'clock", then we have some tough challenges.